# In amazon eks - how to view logs which are prior to eks fargate node creation and logs while pods is starting up

Tags: amazon-eks

I'm using amazon EKS fargate. I can see container logs using fluentbit side car etc no problem at all. But those logs ONLY show what is happening inside the container AFTER it has started up

I enabled aws eks cluster logging fully

Now I would like to see logs in cloudwatch which is equivalent of

```
kubectl describe pod
```

command

I have searched the ENTIRE cloudwatch clustername log group and am not able to find logs like

> "pulling image into container"
> "efs not mounted"

etc

I want to see logs in cloudwatch  prior to the actual container creation stage

IS it possible at all using eks fargate ?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

You can use Container Insights which can collect metrics by using performance log events using the embedded metric format. The logs are stored in CloudWatch Logs. CloudWatch generates several metrics automatically from the logs which you can view in the CloudWatch console.

In Amazon EKS and Kubernetes, Container Insights uses a containerized version of the CloudWatch agent to discover all of the running containers in a cluster. It then collects performance data at every layer of the performance stack.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-view-metrics.html